# Ignore specific values in coloring in heatmap

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have month column - Jan through Dec as well as 'Annual' value. I want to color heatmap based on Jan through Dec only (ignoring `Annual`). Values against `Annual` should be colored separately. In short gradient should be based on Jan through Dec.

[image: Heatmap]

Code below is working fine but it colors based on all unique values of month column.

**Code**

```
library(RColorBrewer)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

myPalette <- colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(3, "Spectral"), space="Lab")
yaxis <- factor(df22$Year, levels = rev(unique(df22$Year)))

ggplot(df22, aes(x=Month, y=yaxis, fill=`Monthly Returns`)) + geom_tile() + 
  xlab("") + ylab("") + 
  guides(fill = FALSE) +
  scale_x_discrete(position = 'top') +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = myPalette(100)) +
  theme_fivethirtyeight() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
  ) +
  geom_text(label= scales::percent(df22$`Monthly Returns`,accuracy=0.1), 
            size = 3.5)
```

**Data**

```
structure(list(Month = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L), .Label = c("Jan", 
"Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", 
"Nov", "Dec", "Annual"), class = "factor"), Year = c(2016, 2016, 
2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 
2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 2018, 
2018, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 
2020, 2020, 2020, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 
2021, 2021, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021), `Monthly Returns` = c(-0.0455546382927932, 
-0.0793794314513473, 0.0994778392356055, 0.0170703744247217, 
0.0431308748372658, 0.0132714449349653, 0.039149313745751, 0.0152410238808452, 
-0.0207479560262523, -0.0032483155414928, -0.0495369168026747, 
-0.00705970342066962, 0.0427766059762552, 0.0360837088460483, 
0.0302490450982238, 0.00905040881707368, 0.0301290066521883, 
-0.00860613165737639, 0.0510171000111251, -0.0181317207157362, 
-0.0149985938461858, 0.044676701273787, -0.0157646094851437, 
0.0260140100477672, 0.0525075423394753, -0.0499522575153075, 
-0.0349476851688416, 0.057891987545299, -0.0044232087547097, 
-0.00224896419515394, 0.0581559876205109, 0.0282311484801734, 
-0.0698913888620315, -0.0497946886834822, 0.0416646520083313, 
-0.00623476893375712, -0.0034869756564318, -0.00542325250964097, 
0.0720534160769843, 0.00711091062419609, 0.0168222388954323, 
-0.0137948669664331, -0.0609718297586985, -0.00334082515221592, 
0.0468481282064616, 0.031440487669275, 0.0142555652225132, 0.00258715177942692, 
-0.0196728260436008, -0.0366116549940638, -0.244973563189387, 
0.148623715952968, 0.00490898463313584, 0.0591404229656986, 0.0726138053972075, 
0.0298393587023052, -0.0189065188181373, 0.0244578656451228, 
0.108708436398415, 0.0703977730606203, -0.033305328712233, 0.0560050298648093, 
-0.000802571331406262, -0.0113053287909243, 0.0760821911971872, 
0.00587662594506211, 0.00050777370424187, 0.0792004231228312, 
0.0251693738851843, 0.00797118377832791, 0.0329671724487319, 
0.282651940477815, 0.0367452321549714, 0.119571125993303, 0.145843113875452, 
0.252922033336702)), row.names = c(NA, -76L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken the liberty to simplify your data frame and also plotting code, trying to boil it down to the essential. I've renamed your returns column because it's much easier to code without back ticks, and instead I named the legend using the `scale` function.

What you're trying to achieve requires two separate fill scales for different parts of your data. Meaning, you need to plot the data separately, e.g. with two calls to `geom_tile`. You can create a second fill scale for example with `ggnewscale`.

In general, from both visualisation and coding perspective, I feel you might fare better by creating two plots separately, and stitch them together with for example `patchwork`. This will avoid the hassle of plotting different parts of your data, avoids the use of data frames that contain both values and aggregation and also will create a visual separation between measurements and aggregated values.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mapping = aes(x = Month, y = as.character(Year))) +
  geom_tile(data = subset(df22, Month != "Annual"), aes(fill = returns)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c("Monthly returns") +
  ggnewscale::new_scale_fill() +
  geom_tile(data = subset(df22, Month == "Annual"), aes(fill = returns)) +
  scale_fill_continuous("Annual") +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = levels(df22$Month))
```

[image]

data

```
df22 <- structure(list(
  Month = structure(c(
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L,
    8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L,
    11L, 12L, 13L, 13L
  ), .Label = c(
    "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May",
    "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Annual"
  ), class = "factor"),
  Year = c(
    2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016,
    2016, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017,
    2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2016, 2017
  ), returns = c(
    -0.0455546382927932,
    -0.0793794314513473, 0.0994778392356055, 0.0170703744247217,
    0.0431308748372658, 0.0132714449349653, 0.039149313745751,
    0.0152410238808452, -0.0207479560262523, -0.0032483155414928,
    -0.0495369168026747, -0.00705970342066962, 0.0427766059762552,
    0.0360837088460483, 0.0302490450982238, 0.00905040881707368,
    0.0301290066521883, -0.00860613165737639, 0.0510171000111251,
    -0.0181317207157362, -0.0149985938461858, 0.044676701273787,
    -0.0157646094851437, 0.0260140100477672, 0.0329671724487319,
    0.282651940477815
  )
), row.names = c(NA, -26L), class = c(
  "tbl_df",
  "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```